# Unable to log into serial terminal using Plink and Python pexpect module

Tags: python, pexpect, asa

I have a set of Cisco firewalls that I have to wipe all the data from. I want to automate this by using Python (on a Windows machine) and PuTTY Link (Plink) on the command line.

The problem I keep running into is when I try to log into the firewall's console with a username and password. When I directly access the console from my computer and put in the username and password, there's no problem and I get access. However, when I try to use my Python script, it doesn't work.

I am using the `pexpect` module for Python, specifically the `PopenSpawn` class that works on Windows. Here's the portion of my code that catches the username and password prompts and is supposed to send the corresponding input:

```py
def login(shell, username, password):
    ...
    shell.expect("Username: ")
    sleep(1)                      # Inserted to keep input from going faster than the console
    shell.sendline(username)
    shell.expect("Password: ")
    sleep(1)                      # ^^
    shell.sendline(password)
```

The two `shell.expect` function calls read the output from the firewall's console until they encounter the specific pattern they're looking for, which is `"Username: "` and `"Password: "`, respectively. Those work just fine.

The two `shell.sendline` function calls are supposed to send a string as input to the firewall's console and then send a newline afterwards.

There's a call to `sleep` in between to help buffer the input.

I have the `shell` process set up so it prints the firewall's output to the screen as it executes. What I see when I run it is this:

```
[ a bunch of booting stuff... ]

Username: <username>
<password>
<username>
Password: <password>
```

where `<username>` and `<password>` are my actual credentials. I don't know why they come out that way, but it isn't working how it is right now.